# Error in w2v_train(trainFile = file_train, modelFile = model, stopWordsFile = file_stopwords (full error text below)

Tags: r, nlp, word-embedding

Full error text: **Error in w2v_train(trainFile = file_train, modelFile = model, stopWordsFile = file_stopwords, : Expecting a single string value: [type=closure; extent=1].**

I am trying to run a word embedding analysis using this data https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/therohk/million-headlines?resource=download to obtain:

1. top 25 closest words to focus word
2. plot these 25 words
3. compare same analysis with different data (JSTOR data on articles with "populism"  https://constellate.org/dataset/f53e497b-844e-2b60-ec2f-b9c54d2e334e?unigrams=political,%20social)

I loaded all the data and necessary packages, as well as pre-processing the ABCNews data for the analysis. (See code)

```
#Loading necessary packages
install.packages(c("tidyverse", "tidytext", "word2vec", "Rtsne", "future", "jstor", "magritrr", "ggplot2", "dplyr"))
library("tidyverse")
library("tidytext")
library("word2vec")
library("Rtsne")
library("future")
library("jstor")
library(magrittr)
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

#Preprocessing abcnews data
##Select text data from csv file ABC NEWS FILE
head(abcnews_pop)
abc_pop_text <- abcnews_pop %>%
  select("headline_text")
head(abc_pop_text)
```

I then used the following code to process the embedding:

```
#ABCNews data
text_news<-abc_pop_text%>%
  txt_clean_word2vec(.,ascii = TRUE, alpha = TRUE, tolower = TRUE, trim = TRUE)

set.seed(123456789)
news_model<-word2vec(x=text, type = "cbow", dim = 500, iter = 50)
embedding_news<-as.matrix(news_model)
```

The first function (text_news<-abc_pop...) ran smoothly. However, the second one (set.seed(123456789) news_model...) puts out this mistake:

**Error in w2v_train(trainFile = file_train, modelFile = model, stopWordsFile = file_stopwords, : Expecting a single string value: [type=closure; extent=1].**

Does anyone know how to address this?

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in naming objects/variables. This has been resolved, thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).